# How to fix the "~ no response on stdout ~" error in HackerRank?

Tags: c

I am trying to solve this problem on HackerRank and once I submit my solution, the compiler shows `wrong answer` and it shows `~ no response on stdout ~` in the output window. How do I fix this?

> Question:
>
> Given a 6X6 2D Array A,
>
> ```
> 1 1 1 0 0 0
> 0 1 0 0 0 0
> 1 1 1 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0
> ```
>
> We define an hourglass in A to be a subset of values with indices falling in this pattern in A's graphical representation:
>
> ```
> a b c
>   d
> e f g
> ```
>
> There are 16 hourglasses in A, and an hourglass sum is the sum of an hourglass' values.
>
> Task
>
> Calculate the hourglass sum for every hourglass in A, then print the maximum hourglass sum.

I have already tried solving the problem. I just can't get rid of this error message. The logic and the solution seem to be correct.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *readline();
char **split_string(char *);

void func(int arr[][100]) {
    int hgs[4][4];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
           hgs[i][j] = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j+1] + arr[i][j+2] +
                       arr[i+1][j+1] +
                       arr[i+2][j] + arr[i+2][j+1] + arr[i+2][j+2];
        }
    }
    int max = hgs[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (hgs[i][j] > max)
                max = hgs[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("%d", max);
}

int main() {
    int **arr = malloc(6 * sizeof(int*));

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        *(arr + i) = malloc(6 * (sizeof(int)));

        char **arr_item_temp = split_string(readline());

        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            char* arr_item_endptr;
            char* arr_item_str = *(arr_item_temp + j);
            int arr_item = strtol(arr_item_str, &arr_item_endptr, 10);

            if (arr_item_endptr == arr_item_str || *arr_item_endptr != 
'\0') {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            *(*(arr + i) + j) = arr_item;
       }
    }
    func(**arr);
    return 0;
}

char *readline() {
    size_t alloc_length = 1024;
    size_t data_length = 0;
    char* data = malloc(alloc_length);

    while (true) {
        char *cursor = data + data_length;
        char *line = fgets(cursor, alloc_length - data_length, stdin);

        if (!line) {
            break;
        }
        data_length += strlen(cursor);
        if (data_length < alloc_length - 1 || data[data_length - 1] == 
'\n') {
            break;
        }

        size_t new_length = alloc_length << 1;
        data = realloc(data, new_length);
        if (!data) {
            break;
        }

        alloc_length = new_length;
    }

    if (data[data_length - 1] == '\n') {
        data[data_length - 1] = '\0';
    }

    data = realloc(data, data_length);

    return data;
}

char **split_string(char *str) {
    char **splits = NULL;
    char *token = strtok(str, " ");

    int spaces = 0;

    while (token) {
        splits = realloc(splits, sizeof(char*) * ++spaces);
        if (!splits) {
            return splits;
        }

        splits[spaces - 1] = token;

        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return splits;
}
```

Expected output is `19` for the sample input, but I am not getting any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very complicated for this simple program, but the problem might be very simple:

- The prototype for `func` should be:

  ```
  void func(int **arr)
  ```
- You should end your output with a newline:

  ```
      printf("%d\n", max);
  ```
- You should pass the array to `func` this way:

  ```
      func(arr);
  ```

Here is a simplified version of the `func` code:

```
void func(int **arr) {
    int i, j, cur, max = INT_MIN;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cur = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j+1] + arr[i][j+2] +
                  arr[i+1][j+1] +
                  arr[i+2][j] + arr[i+2][j+1] + arr[i+2][j+2];
            if (max < cur)
                max = cur;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", max);
}
```

Here is a much simplified version of the whole program:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int grid[6][6];
    int i, j, cur, max = INT_MIN;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &grid[i][j]) != 1)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cur = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j+1] + arr[i][j+2] +
                  arr[i+1][j+1] +
                  arr[i+2][j] + arr[i+2][j+1] + arr[i+2][j+2];
            if (max < cur)
                max = cur;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No. Actually, I only typed the func function. In addition to that I had to write the function call statement in the main function. Rest all code was already there. I cannot remove those  parts of the code.

Comment: @AdityaG901: such a bad example of overly complicated code for a simple problem. Just fix the code for function `func` and its invocation along my remarks then.

Comment: I tried implementing both the changes you have mentioned including initialising max with INT_MIN. The output comes as 1104762770

Comment: It just produces junk value every single time I run it

Comment: @AdityaG901: Did you change the prototype and calling syntax? Do you compile on your own system with warnings enabled or just on the challenge site? How do you see the output?

Comment: I compile it on the challenge site. I just run the program and see the output in the site itself

Comment: Oh wow. I changed function prototype and now I got it. Thanks a lot Chqrlie. Thank you so much really

Comment: Yup. Sure. But I don't have enuf reputation